# How to automate console scenario using TCL script?

Tags: tcl, expect

I want to automate the following scenario:

1. Login into a router
2. Give reload
3. When reloading a router, press ESP key continuously.
4. When pressing a ESP key , boot> prompt will come. execute some commands in this.

I can do the above things manually, using "Teraterm" and console. But how to do this inside a TCL script.

Please help me to do this.

Thanks,
Balu P.

Comment: What platform are you on? (The answer will involve Expect, but knowing the platform will help people write the code for you.) And is ESP the escape key, the one that might sometimes produce `^[` in a console?

Comment: I have written following TCL/Expect script. 
 
 spawn telnet 1.1.1.1
 expect "*ogin:"
 send "test\r"
 expect "*word:" 
 send "test\r"
 expect "*>"
 send "enable\r"
 expect "*#"
 #send "configure terminal\r"
 #expect "*#" 
 #send "self\r"
 #expect "*#"


send "reload\r"
expect "(y/n):"
send "y\r" 
after 20000 ; # Need to press ESP key continuously here

I want to put ESP key when waiting here to get boot prompt. Please help  me to do this.

Comment: @balu: please update your post with the code. Putting code in the comment makes it hard to read and understand.

Comment: What is this `ESP` key? Did you mean the Escape (esc) key?

Comment: @Hai Vu.. Thanks for your comments. I mean "Esc" key in keyboard. And I am new to here, could you please guide me how to put code in comment block?. I tried inserting 4 spaces as shown in "http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code" URL. Please guide me to do this.

Comment: I have used console server, reverse telnet option to automate this scenario and its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have use console server to automate this. Its working fine

Answer (score 1):

You first need to find an interactive *console* program that you can issue the commands from. You may find that `plink.exe` from the PuTTY suite is suitable. The system `telnet.exe` is not suitable, as it has a special flag set on it that prevents automation, and TeraTerm isn't suitable because it is a GUI program as far as I can see (GUI program automation is *very* difficult to say the least, and you probably don't want to do it if there's any easier way).

Once you can do the task interactively, plug it inside of an expect script. It's fairly straight forward.

1. Start with `spawn`, making the program run and passing in the arguments required to connect to the other system.
2. Interact with the remote system.

   1. Listen for a suitable prompt with `expect`. (Remember, this might include prompts to send a username and password!)
   2. Tell it what to do with `send`. Remember that **`\r`** is how you send a <kbd>Return</kbd>.
3. When you're done, `close`.

Of course, things get more complex when you're also dealing with conditionals, error conditions and timeouts; `expect` can handle those, but the code is a bit more complex. Ask another question once you've got a *concrete* problem we can help you with.

Comment: Hi Donal Fellows, Thanks for your help. I tried to use plink. I am able to connect to the router. But when I give reload "Its shows FATAL ERROR: CONNECTION RESET BY PEER". I want to press continuous escape key when router is reloading to get boot> prompt. Is there any way to access console of that router through TCL/Expect script.please help me to do this.

Comment: I have used console server, reverse telnet option to automate this scenario and its working fine.